# Log on standard output

Tags: logs, systemd, init.d

I'm using Debian Jessie and I'm having big `init.d` script which starts or stops variety of daemons (more than 10), which list is taken from configuration file. Using `systemctl restart parstart.service` writes every message on `/var/log/syslog/`, but I really need this logs on standard output.
Is it possible to get log on standard output using `systemctl restart service`?